# Where do I define XML for the Toolbar widget in Android 5.0?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

Okay, I've been going through several StackOverflow posts now, but I'm still confused as to where this xml for my Toolbar goes.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:background=”@styles/colorPrimary” />
```

Does it go in my `/layout/activity_main.xml`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Toolbar is a generalization of Action bars for use within app layouts, now to answer your question there are two practices:

**Bad practice:**

Bad practice is to define the Toolbar in every layouts.

**Standard practice:**

Standard practice is to define a layout and reference it in a base activity. You just need to include this Toolbar layout in whichever layout you want (by using `<include>`) and extend the defined base activity in whichever activity.

This standard practice will help you keeping a single code base for Toolbar and save your time from defining Toolbar every time.

**Example: Google I/O 2014 android app**

[toolbar_actionbar_with_headerbar.xml](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/toolbar_actionbar_with_headerbar.xml)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:iosched="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    iosched:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    iosched:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    iosched:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    iosched:contentInsetStart="?actionBarInsetStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
```

This toolbar layout is referenced in settings activity as given below:

[activity_settings.xml](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/res/layout/activity_settings.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.SettingsActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar_with_headerbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Helpful and very informative answer. Thanks for helping me understand this!

Comment: @awkwardgiraffe welcome and cheers! Google I/O is the best open source app for exploring new styles, guidelines implemented and code.

Comment: @PareshMayani can you help me on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903014/android-adt-23-0-4-is-showing-compile-with-api21android-4-xl-preview-instead

Comment: @LOG_TAG hmm I haven't came across this issue so no idea!

Comment: axml's include tag is a valid approach for those who don't like inherited layouts

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM agree!

Answer (score 3):

As for me, I usually make a ToolbarActivity. Next, if you want your activity to have a toolbar, you just need to `YourActivity extends ToolbarActivity`.

```
public class ToolbarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, null);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        layout.addView(contentView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context=".ToolbarActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

</LinearLayout>
```