# Android ADT 23.0.4 is showing Compile With: API21:Android 4.X(L Preview) Instead of API21:Android 5.0

Tags: android, adt, android-5.0-lollipop, android-sdk-tools

**What I did?**

I updated my SDK from L preview API 20 to new Android 5.0 API 21 andADT to 23.0.4 in my Ubuntu.

**Problem:**

Android ADT 23.0.4 not showing `Compile With: API21:Android 4.X(L Preview)` Instead of `Compile With:API21:Android 5.0`

**Screenshots:**

*(Files-->New-->Android Application Project-->Compile with/target sdk)*

**[image: Screenshots:]**

*Highlighted in red texts should be changed to Compile With:API21:Android 5.0!!`*

SDK(updated to latest):

[image]

ADT(updated to latest):

[image]

***it's a bug ? or So I'm only the one facing this or it's just error?, I need to download the fresh copy of SDK to solve this error!!??***

**After the project created:**

[image]

[Bug reported](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/24F86Fg_OMY)

Comment: You first update your Eclipse with latest version......

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Eclipse downloaded from http://developer.android.com

Comment: I had the same problem in Windows, but it does not seem to have any side effects.

Comment: @LOG_TAG, You are welcome. I was also struggling to fix it at first, but only in vain. So now I just let it be... Hope it will be fixed automatically in next update or something.

Comment: I just noticed the same problem here. 
Any solution so far?

Comment: @John No! We just need to ignore it! it does not seem to have any side effects (Qianqian mentioned already! FYI it's right time to move from Eclipse to Android Studio :)

Comment: @LOG_TAG the only thing that holds me back to switch to Android Studio is that it's still in beta phase. I hope for a stable version soon.

Comment: @John yes Stable (coming soonish)!! http://tools.android.com/download/studio they've just released Android Studio 1.0 Release Candidate 1 http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio1rc1_releasecandidate1released