# Android: What does "X" in version "4.X (L Preview)" and "Preview" in "L Preview" mean, and why does the combination "Android 4.X (L Preview) imply"?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-5.0-lollipop

I have ADT version `23.0.4` and have `Android 5.0`'s `SDK Platform` installed.

I read that the Android 5.0 Lolipop has API level 21. But in Eclipse in the "New Application Project" wizard, it shows the highest API level to be L Preview and then API 21: Android 4.X (L Preview).

1. What does this confusing sorta **comination "Android 4.X"** (implies it is a 4.somthing version of Android SDK) **and "L Preview"** (L for Lollipop?) mean?

And **what does "X" say in "4.X"**?

2. Why are they using the word "Preview" in L Preview to indicate they Lollipop version?** Why didn't they write something like "API 21: Android 5.0 (Lollipop)"** like they used to for old versions?

Comment: Have you tried update eclipse?

Comment: @Mou Yes it's the latest version

Comment: A similar bug is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26903014/android-adt-23-0-4-is-showing-compile-with-api21android-4-xl-preview-instead

Comment: It doesn't look like a bug, does it?

Comment: What Android SDK Build Tools do you have? It doesn't always show as an update, but as a new package, so you have to manually select it to install. The latest is 21.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the final version of "Android 5.0 (Lollipop)" was release, Google published a beta (or preview) version of the new API. At this time it was not clear (in public) if this version would be called Android 4.5 or Android 5.0. For the "L" in the name, I can only say Google uses an alphabetically order of there version names. So after KitKat they had to use some name with an L as first letter. -> [Android version history](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history)

So they chose to publish it as a "L preview" version.

After publishing the final version they renamed API Level 21 to "Android 5.0 (Lollipop)"

Comment: Thank you. But "Android 5.0 (Lollipop)" doesn't show in Eclipse "New Application Wizard" :s

Comment: I think you have to use now "Android Studio" as IDE. I don't think eclipse will be support any longer.

Comment: I don't know if anyone else faces this, but Android Studio slows down my computer a lot.