# android toolbar inside a tab

Tags: java, android, tabs, toolbar

I want to make a toolbar inside one of my tabs but nothing works for me. Can this even be done? I currently have a toolbar above my tabs but i need it to appear inside the first tab.

Here's the code (with the toolbar above tabs):

```
import ...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = {"Projects", "People", "Files"};
int Numboftabs = 3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); 
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_primary, menu);
    return true;
}

final ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.addButton) {
        final TextView noProject = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.NOPROJECT);
        final ListAdapter addAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, R.id.listFrame, listItems);
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(addAdapter);

        noProject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        listItems.add("New Project");

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent switchToEdit = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        TeamCreate.class);
                startActivity(switchToEdit);
            }
        });
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

First tab:

```
import ...

public class Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `setSupportActionBar()`, you should be able to just put the `Toolbar` into the layout for `Tab1`, AFAIK. I haven't had a chance to play with `Toolbar` yet, though I really do need to get around to doing it...

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please give a code example? I'm relatively new to android and java, afraid I might screw something up

Comment: "could you please give a code example?" -- no, because, as I wrote, I haven't had a chance to play with `Toolbar` yet. A Google search on `android toolbar layout` turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708230/where-do-i-define-xml-for-the-toolbar-widget-in-android-5-0 and http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar challenge with a non-standard toolbar and tabs and got past it, though frankly the results were odd looking.  You can probably get the toolbar to work under the tab using a similar technique, however it may leave your users scratching their heads.  Your technique will have 2 toolbars, one holding the TabLayout widget and another one inside the fragment(s) in the ViewPager.

I was using Material Design tabs for the Detail view in my app. It looked fine until I did the 2-pane Master-Detail view for tablets.  Then I had an issue with the tabs wanting to be directly under the toolbar, but no obvious way to have the Master & Detail share the toolbar with the tabs only showing up under the Detail portion of the screen.

I got it working by:

1. Create a "NoActionBar" style in styles.xml, then refer to it in your main layout using "android:theme="@style/AppTheme".

   ```
   <!-- Turn off normal application bar so we can put our toolbars where we please.
    Do this by replacing "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" with NoActionBar
    per http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-action-bar-dialog-using-toolbar/ -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialTheme.Base"/>
   <style name="MaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   ```
2. Toss android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and just use a LinearLayout.
3. Here is a snippet that has the toolbar containing the tabs only taking up part of the screen real estate rather than the entire width. Note that the toolbar has "app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways":

   ```
     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:name="com.android.bazemom.popularmovies.TabContainerFragment"
   >
   <!-- second toolbar that will be used for the tabs -->
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
       android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
       />

   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabanim_tabs"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

   <!-- Helps handing the Fragments to load for each Tab -->
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/tabanim_viewpager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
   ```

Here is what the Master-Detail view looked like on wide tablet. The tabs are circled in green. The toolbar with an action is above the tabs.
[image: wide tablet screen capture showing tabs using only part of screen width.]